# vue component works locally but not release?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

The components I wrote using VueJS work properly on localhost, but when I get the release it doesn't work. While the component is on localhost, it appears on the page but it does not appear on the page after receiving the release. Why do you think it doesn't work?

Localhost;

[image]

Release;

[image]

Comment: You should show the code you wrote and how you registered the component

Comment: I upload my code to npm and download it from npm in another project.

Answer (score 0):

could you share the code of the component?

I got like this problem and the issue was with the name of the component

Comment: I shared below.

Comment: it's hard to understand your problem without seeing your code, but from what I saw in the image I think the issue is with the component name, so what you should do is changing the component name to PascalName and when you used you should use it in this way:

`
<DpSwitch />
// or
<dp-switch />
`
and in the register you should write something like this
`
Vue.component("VForm", VForm);
`
its better than ` Vue.component(VForm.name, VForm); `